# Best tool for testing IE from a Mac - without a PC

Tags: css, browser

What is the best way/service to test cross browser compatibility for a website design. I am on a Mac  and need to see across all mac browsers and all PC browsers as well (obviously).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is Virtual Machine.

- [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/) for free. I think more than enough for your purposes.
- [Parallels Desktop 5 for Mac](http://www.parallels.com/eu/products/desktop/).
- [VMware Fusion 3](http://www.vmware.com/products/fusion/).

Answer (score 1):

http://litmusapp.com/ has done DocType which SO has partnered with.

You could, if you have an Intel Mac, get a copy of Windows 7 Professional, which includes XP Mode and install it as a bootcamp partition.

Answer (score 1):

[Browsershots](http://www.browsershots.com) or [Browsercam](http://www.browsercam.com) are cool

Answer (score 0):

You could create a Virtual PC in VirtualBox or VMWare Fusion for this purpose.

Kindness,

Dan

Answer (score 0):

You could run Windows virtualized in a [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming an Intel Mac, have you considered virtualization? [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/) is free, there are other (cheap) similar solutions.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said you can use a VM and run any version of Windows in it. It helps to also have IETester in order to test several IE versions.